# Парсер расписания колледжа

Tags: c#, html

Хотелось сделать бота для телеграмм на C#, но не могу понять как спарсить страницу расписания..
Вот сайт:https://bppk.info/schedule/student4/212.html
На нем чистая таблица, нету классов.. Возможно ли получать какой пара будет и название ее?
**Например**:

1. ничего
2. дискретная математика
3. русский
   и т.д.

Я выводил полную страницу, но меня ставило в ступор что нету классов в таблице

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Берите любой парсер HTML и вперед, там простая структура. Ищите `table`, у него берете все `tr`, затем у каждого `tr` забираете уже `td`, на основе полученного формируете класс с данными, готово.

Comment: Библиотека HtmlAgilityPack или AngleSharp поможет.